# Create a Synonym for Enterprise Keywords [2013]

Tags: managed-metadata, managed-metadata-service, enterprise-keywords

In SharePoint 2013 it seems very easy to create synonyms for terms that live under the `Managed Metadata Service` (see first image) but it seems like I am unable to do so with `Keywords` living under the `System` section of the Term Store Management Tool (see image 2). Is there anyway to enable synonyms for System Keywords (Enterprise Keywords)

Synonyms enabled for `Managed Metadata Service` terms
[image]

No option for synonyms in `System -> Keywords`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In a very dull non-techie script free answer, might I suggest creating a new Keywords Term Set called perhaps "Approved Keywords", moving approved Enterprise Keywords into it and then adding the synonyms to the terms in the "Approved Keywords" list.